# User login with Angularjs and Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to find a way to create a simple login form with Angularjs and Firebase. I currently have a simple signup form, which adds a userName into my firebase database. All I need to know is how to get a login page that accepts a user once the userName is identified in the firebase system, and to possibly make a callback error if there is no such userName within the database. This is my signup form:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body ng-controller="userCtrl">
    <div class="centerForm">

        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputUser">Username</label>
            <input type="username" ng-model="userName" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUser" placeholder="username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" ng-model="userPassword" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <table class="nav" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveUser()">Submit</button>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Sign Up</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>       
          </table>
        </form>

    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my sign up code:

```
 <script>
             angular.module('myApp', [])
             .controller('userCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.userName ="";
                $scope.userPassword="";

                $scope.myData = new Firebase( "https://myfirebaseapp.firebaseio.com/")

                $scope.saveUser = function() {
                    $scope.myData.push({userName: $scope.userName});
                };

                });





    </script>
```

My login form would then look something like:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body ng-controller="userCtrl">
    <div class="centerForm">

        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputUser1">Username</label>
            <input type="username" ng-model="userName" class="form-control" id="exampleInputUser1" placeholder="username">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" ng-model="userPassword" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <table class="nav" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="loginUser()">Submit</button>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Sign Up</a></p>
                </td>
            </tr>       
          </table>
        </form>

    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is only putting the username in the firebase, it isn't actually creating an account so you should fix that first before you can actually log in.

Answer (score 5):

[AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html) exists for this reason- to bind Angular with Firebase.

Here's a working example. This is the login controller:

```
var app = angular.module('appName');

app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",
  function($firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://yourtester.firebaseio.com");
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }
]);

app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$http', 'Auth',
  function($scope, $state, $http, Auth) {
    $scope.auth = Auth;
    $scope.auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
      $scope.authData = authData;
    });
    $scope.login = function() {
      Auth.$authWithPassword({
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password
      })
      .then(function(authData) {
        console.log('Logged in as:', authData.uid);
        //$state.go('profile');
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('error:',err);
        //$state.go('login');
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

And this is the login.html file:

```
<body ng-app='appName' ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    <h1>Login!</h1>
    <form ng-submit='login()'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email address</label>
        <input id="email" ng-model='email' type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" ng-model='password' type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: How does this code validate any login by checking if the account is in database or not?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using angular JS and my login function for Firebase looks like this in the controller:

```
app.factory("Auth", ["$firebaseAuth",function($firebaseAuth) {
var ref = new Firebase("https://myfirebaseapp.firebaseio.com");
return $firebaseAuth(ref);
}]);

$scope.login = function() {
    $scope.authObj.$authWithPassword({
      name: $scope.data.name,
      email: $scope.data.email,
      password: $scope.data.password
    }).then(function(authData) {
        authenticated = true;
        console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid, authenticated);
        $location.path("profile");
        check();
    }).catch(function(error) {
        authenticated = false;
        console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
        check();
    });
}
```